Calculating how many classes a relation partitions a set
Just struggling to understand how to calculate how many classes a relation partitions a set into, in particular when the set is over a very large field e.g all integers
The following question is one that I don't know where to start with:
"xSy ⇐⇒ x − y is a multiple of 4.
Where S is the relation defined on the set X = Z
Into how many classes does it partition the set?"
I've looked at other examples online but they all involve sets that are finite such as X = {1,2,...,99} .
In that case, I think the answer would be 4 classes but I just don't know how to work it out when the set is over the whole range of integers

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Could you edit into your question an example you don't know how to solve? But as a general point, one strategy is to construct a set with exactly one element in each equivalence class (assuming by relation you mean equivalence relation, otherwise how does the partition work?), then determine its cardinality.

Find some small numbers that are in the same class. Look for a pattern and generalize.

Hi J.G, thanks for taking the time to help. I edited my post there so I've included the example I dont know how to solve.

@CyclotomicField, so my thinking is that 0,4,8,12,16, etc are all multiples of 4 - do these count as different classes or the same class? Would all the other numbers then that dont fall into this set count as a separate class?

@Joe they're all in the same class. Note that $5-1=4$ but $6-1=5$ so $5$ and $1$ are in the same class but they're not in the same class as $6$.

@CyclotomicField , ok I think I understand what your saying... so would the following be the classes: {0,4,8,12,16,...} {1,5,9,13,17,...} {2,6,10,14,18,...} {3,7,11,15,19,...} ? Meaning that the relation partitions the set into 4 classes?

@Joe yep you got it.
